# Using a IO variable before it has been assigned a value in a Try...Catch...Finally

Tags: vb.net, io, try-catch

I'm trying to use an IO object in VB.net which I'm not initialising from the declaration point. I use the object in several places in a Try..Catch block and then I use it again in the Finally block. For the purpose of my question you can ignore the method calls of my code. VS is showing this warning: Variable 'objSourceDirectory' is used before it has been assigned a value. A null reference exception could result at runtime.

I believe having safe checks in some places in my code the null reference shouldn't happen, but how could I get rid of this warning? I would initialise the variable as empty at declaration point but this can't be possible with IO.DirectoryInfo, as it doesn't have a construction without parameters. How can I fix this?

```
    Dim object1 As IO.DirectoryInfo
    Try
        mlstProcessedFiles = New Global.System.Collections.Generic.List(Of String)
        ' Gather Data from import source
        object1 = New IO.DirectoryInfo(object2.Location)
        MethodD(object2.Location)
        MethodA(object1)
        MethodC(object2.Location)

        ' Work through files found in the source. Detect if the file was moved and add it to the manual processing
        For Each objFile In object1.GetFiles()
            Try
               MethodB(objFile, object2)
                objFile = Nothing
            Catch objFileEx As FileNotFoundException
            Catch objDirEx As DirectoryNotFoundException
                MethodX(mstrERROR_11_MOVED, objDirEx.Message)
                Continue For
            End Try
        Next
    Catch objectException As Exception
        Throw
    Finally
        'Make sure processed files have been moved to their folders
        Method1()
        Method2()
        Method3(object1)
    End Try
```

Comment: You haven't shown `objSourceDirectory` in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't shown `objSourceDirectory` in your code. I assume it is `object1` which is used in the `Finally`.

Yes, you cannot use a variable when it is possible that this variable was not assigned a value. You are using it in the `Finally` which is executed always, **even on error**.

Since you haven't assigned a default value it is possible that you get an exception which causes it to remain unassigned. This compiler error prevents you from careless mistakes.

To fix it you could assign `Nothing`:

```
Dim object1 As IO.DirectoryInfo = Nothing
```

but you should check if it's `Nothing` in the `Finally` or in `Method3`.

In this case you could also move the initilization to the declaration which makes it definitely assigned:

```
Dim object1 As IO.DirectoryInfo = New IO.DirectoryInfo(object2.Location)
```

Note that the compiler is not smart enough  to check if it is possible that an errors is raised before the variable is initialized. It just looks at the `Try` and "thinks": it's possible that here comes an error.

Comment: Thanks, assigning it to nothing + checking if it's nothing at the finally do the job.